# What is deviance in lassoglm

Tags: generalized-linear-model, cross-validation, matlab, lasso

I am trying to fit a lasso penalized logistic regression model to a certain data. I am using lassoglm for that in matlab. I use the following function

[B,FitInfo] = lassoglm(X,Y,'binomial','Lambda',0.01,'CV',10);

Using 10 fold cross validation, it will use different samples every time to fit the model. However, I didn't get what deviance means in this case. Lets say for the first run of cross validation, I have k non zero features. For next run, I have a model with m non zero features and so on. What does deviance then measure and how the plot is generated like using that lassoplot. Suggestion?

Actually, I didn't  get this figure. What does it specify?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to [MATLAB's help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lassoglm.html), deviance is the value of the loss function for the type of model that you are using. It is the value of negative log-likelihood (MSE for linear regression) for your model averaged over the validation folds in the cross-validation procedure.

According to [MATLAB's](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lassoplot.html) help, the two points marked in the graph are:

> Plots the value of Lambda with minimum cross-validated MSE.
>
> Plots the greatest Lambda that is within one standard error of minimum MSE (so makes the sparsest model within that region).

Comment: And what are the bars for. I mean for each point there is a bar. What is that for?

Comment: MATLAB's help says: "Plots error bars for the estimates." To me they look like 1-standard deviation confidence intervals. You can see that for large values of lambda --which produces sparse models-- the variation is smaller, which confirms my guess.

Comment: The bars are the standard deviation of the deviance, computed across the ten cross validation folds.

Answer (score 0):

The green circle and dashed line locate the Lambda with minimal cross-validation error.

The blue circle and dashed line locate the point with minimal cross-validation error plus one standard deviation.